# AttributeError: module 'translators' has no attribute 'google'

Tags: python, pandas, translation, translate

I'm trying to translate a pandas column from multiple different languages to English and found the "translators" library to do so. When I try to use it, I keep getting the following error:

AttributeError: module 'translators' has no attribute 'google'

The line of code producing the error is:

df['Translated Comments'] = df[col_name].apply(lambda x: ts.google(x, to_language='en'))

I was following the following tutorial to try to use this library:

https://towardsdatascience.com/language-translation-using-python-bd8020772ccc

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out... looks like the tutorial is out of date or I just read it wrong. The line of code should read:

df['Translated Comments'] = df[col_name].apply(lambda x: ts.translate_text(x, translator='google', to_language='en'))

The documentation I was looking at was also for an older version. Here is the current documentation:
https://pypi.org/project/translators/